# How can I cast an object to a table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, tablesorter

I have a table. Now I cloned it. when I am using the tablesorter it is saying cannot use it on a type object.

So, how can i cast it to object.

```
var clonedTable = $('#originalTable').clone(); 
$(clonedTable).tablesorter({ 
widgets: ['zebra'],  
headers: { 
 0:{sorter:false}, 
 1:{sorter:false},
 2:{sorter:false},
 3:{sorter:false},
 4:{sorter:false} } 
});
```

Here tablesorter is complaining that: uncaught type error. object[object object] has no method tablesorter

```
Edit:
```

Digging more into code... i notice the cause is this line:

```
 var clonedTableRows= $('clonedTable tr:gt(0)');
```

looks like clonedTableRows is empty... Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: Execute this `console.log( typeof $.fn.tablesorter );`. What is logged?

Comment: Do you actually import the plugin source code `jquery.tablesorter.js`?

Comment: i imported plugin source code. it worked fine if i did table sort on original table

Comment: @ravi posting the exact error-messages would be a good idea.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter' . that is the exact error message i am seeing

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to reproduce your error, it works fine on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pSb2k/

Comment: @nbrooks No need to include the plugin inline... there is an option "add resources" for that;)

Comment: @christoph Oh good to know, never used that before...don't think it would help since there doesn't seem to be a cdn hosted version/direct link anywhere

Comment: Digging more into code... i notice the cause is this line:   var clonedTableRows= $('clonedTable tr:gt(0)');  ....loks like clonedTableRows is empty... Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: @ravi maybe it's another copy/paste error, but you're still referencing the variable `clonedTable` within quotes, which you can't do. To get the rows do this: `$(clonedTable).find('tr:gt(0)')`. *Watch the quotation marks carefully*, since without them you reference a javascript variable, but with them you reference a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nbrooks said, the quotes shouldn't be around the `clonedTable` variable. Try this instead:

```
var clonedTableRows = clonedTable.find('tr:gt(0)');
```

Also, you are initializing the plugin on a cloned object that isn't attached to the DOM. Append the cloned table somewhere, then initialize the plugin:

```
var clonedTable = $('#originalTable').clone()
      // remove duplicate ID
      .removeAttr('id')
      // append it whatever you want
      .appendTo('body')
      // now that it's in the DOM, initialize the plugin
      .tablesorter({ 
        widgets: ['zebra'],  
        headers: { 
          0:{sorter:false}, 
          1:{sorter:false},
          2:{sorter:false},
          3:{sorter:false},
          4:{sorter:false}
        } 
      });
```

Comment: Thanks .I have a question: Now I am doing sorting on cloned table. But I am seeing that all my original table order is also changed based on sorting i did on cloned table. I didnt understand why these two are connected. Cloning is a deep copy right? Is there a way to keep the order of original table untouched when i am sorting on cloned table?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but I would remove the ID from the cloned table... I'll edit the original post. Oh and it's not a "deep" clone unless you use `clone(true)`, then it clones all events attached to the element as well.